# Gradle: Override Class from main sourceSet in Test sourceSet

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, gradle, dagger

I have a Modules class that provides Dagger modules. When running my Unit Tests and androidTests, I would like to override this class, similar to how you can override classes for different build types or flavors.

Is this possible? Currently I am getting a `Duplicate class file found` error when I try to have a class in my `test` sourceSet that has the same qualified name as the corresponding class in the `main` sourceSet.

Ultimately, I want to provide the database a little differently during unit tests.

Comment: This is what dependency-injection is for ;)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth yes - which is why I am using it.

Comment: Ok, so then is the only issue that your test class has an identical (qualified) name to your real class?  Surely that's trivially circumventable by naming it `TestDatabase` (or whatever)?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth if it doesn't have the same qualified name, then how will all the code in my `main` sourceSet know to use it. Or rather, how can I tell the code in my `main` sourceSet to use `TestDataModule` instead of `DataModule`?

I want to use the same objectGraph across all my tests. If I have to recreate the objectGraph - that's a problem because of how long my data takes to initialize.

Comment: But isn't *that* what DI is about?  I haven't used Dagger, so I can't comment on how to leverage it, but the basic notion is that during testing, you supply a `TestDataModule` instance rather than a `DataModule` instance.  Alternatively, you supply a factory that constructs the relevant instances.

Comment: Weird - okay the issue was that I was getting this "Duplicate class file found" error - but that error doesn't seem to matter.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is not by overriding classes (which you've already noticed doesn't work). Rather, you could define a common Interface, and then have two different implementations of it. One for `main` and one for `test`.

That way, the test can provide a `Test<Something>` object while the application code provides a `<Something>`, and the class you're testing won't know the difference.